# ORA 00936 Missing Expression Error

Tags: c#

```
 protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection())
        {
            conn.ConnectionString = connectionstring;
            conn.Open();
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = "Insert into PFC.Trial(FAME)VALUES(@FAME)";
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("@FAME", TextBox1.Text));
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();     
        }
    }
    }
}
```

error is here
error is in last line
the cmd.executenonquery();

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the symbol when setting up the parameter, also, should be a colon instead of @ for Oracle:

```
using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection())
{
        conn.ConnectionString = connectionstring;
        conn.Open();
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "Insert into PFC.Trial(FAME)VALUES(:FAME)";
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("FAME", TextBox1.Text));
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();     
}
```